# Binding media server to a different host

Tags: nginx-reverse-proxy

I am trying to reverse proxy my local home NAS.
What I would like to do is, now my media server listens on `nas:8096`, but I would like to reverse proxy it to be `media`.
I tried to bind it with Nginx Proxy Manager, but it doesn't seem to work:

```
server {
        listen 80;
        location media/ {
                    proxy_pass http://192.168.0.100:8096;
  }
}
```

I know its a stupid try... :D

Thanks.